# Hide a specific action button conditionally in Woocommerce admin Orders list

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce, orders

I Would like to add some CSS to the order admin page to hide a custom order action button, but only if the order contains only downloadable products.

This is the function I need to load conditionally:

```
add_action( 'admin_head', 'hide_custom_order_status_dispatch_icon' );
function hide_custom_order_status_dispatch_icon() {
    echo '<style>.widefat .column-order_actions a.dispatch { display: none; }</style>';
}
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With CSS it's **not be possible**.

Instead you can hook in `woocommerce_admin_order_actions` filter hook, where you will be able to check if all order item are downloadable and then remove the action button **"dispatch"**:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_admin_order_actions', 'custom_admin_order_actions', 900, 2 );
function custom_admin_order_actions( $actions, $the_order ){
    // If button action "dispatch" doesn't exist we exit
    if( ! $actions['dispatch'] ) return $actions;

    // Loop through order items
    foreach( $the_order->get_items() as $item ){
        $product = $item->get_product();
        // Check if any product is not downloadable
        if( ! $product->is_downloadable() )
            return $actions; // Product "not downloadable" Found ==> WE EXIT
    }
    // If there is only downloadable products, We remove "dispatch" action button
    unset($actions['dispatch']);

    return $actions;
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of the active child theme (or active theme).*

This is untested but should work…

> You will have to check that `'dispatch'` is the correct slug for this action button…

Comment: Thank you for helping me out here,  it is working perfectly.