# Remove WooCommerce admin order action from order preview

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, preview, orders

I want to remove, for shop-managers, the ability to mark an order as completed. To do so, I used the following based on *"[Hide a specific action button conditionally in Woocommerce admin Orders list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48399729/hide-a-specific-action-button-conditionally-in-woocommerce-admin-orders-list/48401409#48401409)"* answer in my theme's functions.php file:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_admin_order_actions', 'custom_admin_order_actions', 900, 2 );
function custom_admin_order_actions( $actions, $the_order ){
    if(isset(wp_get_current_user()->roles[0]) && wp_get_current_user()->roles[0] == 'shop-manager') 
        unset($actions['complete']);

    return $actions;
}
```

By this, I succesfully removed the complete button from the shop_order page. However, the shop-manager is still able to complete the order using the Complete button that appears in the order preview. To avoid this, I tried the next action after the previous one:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_preview_start', 'custom_display_order_data_in_admin' );
function custom_display_order_data_in_admin(){
    // Call the stored value and display it
    echo '<div>Class = "button hidden wc-action-button wc-action-button-complete complete"</div><br>'; 
}
```

However, this does not remove the button from the preview window because it does not substitute the line in the code.

Is there a way to remove this ability from the shop_order page and the order preview at once? If not, how can I hide this button from the preview window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the "complete" update order status button from admin order preview for "Shop manager" user role, use the following:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_admin_order_preview_actions', 'filter_admin_order_preview_actions', 10, 2 );
function filter_admin_order_preview_actions( $actions, $order ) {
    if( current_user_can('shop-manager') && isset($actions['status']['actions']['complete']) ) {
        unset($actions['status']['actions']['complete']);
    }
    return $actions;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.